# Git push option for aborting if branch on remote doesn't equal given commit-id?

Tags: git

Is there some `git push` option (some obscure syntax perhaps) for making it abort if the branch on the server side doesn't equal some specified commit-id?

I'm writing house keeping script that purges branches on remote it deems stale, and it'll be run periodically, but I'm concerned about someone else pushing to a branch the script is targeting, during the critical seconds between when the script is evaluating and actually pushing.

Comment: No single command to do this - you have to pull and check, which creates an unavoidable delay. Depending on your network environment, that race condition is unlikely to occur, *ever*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is.  It's not too obscure: it's `git push --force-with-lease`.

The way you tell the two Gits involved what hash ID you expect the *other* Git to have, is to set something in *your* Git.  The thing you set in your Git is your *remote-tracking name*.  For instance, I created the slightly silly / pointless name `zilly` in a dummy repository I keep for testing:

```
git push origin master:zilly
```

Now my local Git has `origin/zilly` (full name `refs/remotes/origin/zilly`) containing the hash ID I think they—`origin`—have in their `refs/heads/zilly`, so:

```
git push --force-with-lease --delete origin zilly
```

If I've updated their `zilly` since then (by whatever means), or changed my idea of their `zilly`, I get:

```
 ! [rejected]        (delete) -> zilly (stale info)
error: failed to push some refs to <url>
```

Note that (a) this works for regular force-push updates, and (b) you can spell the delete operation in various ways; the key is still this `--force-with-lease`, which means you have to have `origin/whatever` in your local repository.  That's fairly convenient since `git fetch origin --prune` keeps your local repository up to date.

Comment: Oh wow, that's great! And your explanation was perfect. I see there's also [a `--force-with-lease=<refname>:<expect>` variation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---force-with-leaseltrefnamegtltexpectgt) so I don't need to juggle tracking branches making it even better.  A quick blame on git-push docs show it was added [six years ago in v1.8.5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28f5d176110d2ed768a0a49159993c7a02d8cb15) so it's been around for ages!

Comment: Yes, though in practice, it's pretty reasonable to run `git fetch origin` once up front anyway in order to evaluate which branches you think should get deleted, after which you don't need the name:expect stuff. (I like to set `fetch.prune` to `true` to auto-clean as well.)

Comment: You're right. I'd mixed up *remote-tracking branches* with [something else entirely](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---set-upstream) and also wasn't considering the interaction with `git fetch` and the snapshot I automatically get. Just `--force-with-lease` alone indeed creates a very elegant solution!